# Labview FPGA Simulation Timing

Tags: simulation, fpga, labview

This is a very basic question. I can't simulate a PWM file, in system time, from its FPGA VI file.

***Details***

For a *NI cRIO-9067* + *LabVIEW 2016* + *Windows 8* system, under *FPGA Interface Mode*, I have the *Test VI No.1.vi* NI LabVIEW file and the corresponding FPGA *Desktop Execution Node* block file *Test VI No.1 DEN.vi* as suggested in the Getting Started information [[1]](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/51859/en/) [[2]](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/372596b.pdf).

In both files, the *Low Pulse* and *High Pulse* Numeric Controls are filled with the *1000* value. The *Loop Timer* block is set as "mSec" *Counter Unit* and "32 Bit" *Size of Internal Counter*.

The compiled FPGA version of the first file executes a square wave changing each 1 second, as expected, after 7 minutes of local compilation.

Under *Simulation (Simulated I/O)* as Execution Mode, and for reproducing approximatedly and by trial and error the square wave timing every 1 second, I need to put the value *1750* in the *Clock Ticks* field, from the *FPGA 40MHz Onboard Clock* reference clock, shown in the block options.

I dont understand this block, and why i should not put any close divisor of 40,000,000 at the *Clock Ticks* field, or simply, the value 1. Basically i dont understand how to "time" these FPGA simulations.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Comment: It sounds as if you're following some sort of tutorial or exercise, can you link to it? The LabVIEW manuals should be available on the NI site.

Comment: Added..........

Answer (score 1):

The desktop execution node is designed for time based simulation you are definately on the right track.

What you are setting at the top is the number of cycles that are executed each time you call the node. In your case you have 1750 ticks so around 43.75us of simulated time per iteration.

To simulate in real time you need to make sure that you execute the same amount of simulated time as the simulation loop takes to run. In your case, you have no timing in your simulation loop so why 1750 works for you is because that is probably how long that loop takes to execute.

If you put a loop timer in of 1ms and set the clock ticks to 40,000 (1ms simulated time) then I think you will find that it also works.

In some cases it may be beneficial to execute faster than real time so you would just have to account for that in your maths. For example if you set the clock ticks to 40 (1us simulated time) then you can count the number of iterations and multiply by 1us to get the actual clock time.